# how to execute a .exe file remotely on a machine in the network and chk the status of the code

Tags: windows

how to execute a .exe file remotely on a machine in the network and chk the status of the code,i have tried psexec which is very slow

Comment: PSEXEC is probably your best choice if you want to do this without extra software installations and such. Can you show us the command you're trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

This should be on serverfault.com as you didn't indicate you need to programmatically do this. But why not use SSH?

Comment: The 'windows' tag suggest that SSH is not a reasonable option here, I think.

Comment: Well the poster didn't give us much info to work with. Its easy to install SSH on windows. If he can't or won't that's another issue that only he could tell us.